# Component Views don't appear when creating a new menu item

Tags: component, development, menu-item, view

In Joomla 3.2, I have a component with many views. I want to create a menu item that will point to each separate view. For example:

`/view1` would redirect to `?option=com_mycomponent&view=view1`

`/view2` would redirect to `?option=com_mycomponent&view=view2`

etc.

The issue im having is that none of the views I've created do not appear in the selector when I try to select a menu item type.

Is there a way to get those views to show up in the admin item type selector popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insure that there is a matching XML file for the view in the \tmpl folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <layout title="COM_MYCOMPONENT_VIEW_TITLE" option="View">
        <message>
                        <![CDATA[COM_MYCOMPONENT_VIEW_DESC]]>
        </message>
    </layout>
</metadata>
```